# Radio buttons always "false" in params

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, radio-button, form-for

I don't understand... The radio button is always returning false, the rest of the form works.  I had to put "false" for the third argument for the "radio_button" form_for helper method, however, that shouldn't affect the outcome.  Any idea what's going on?

```
   <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label :delivery_method, :class => 'control-label required' %>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="hidden" name="auction_holder[delivery_method]" value="">
        <% ['Rail', 'Truck', 'Barge'].each_with_index do |t, i| %>
        <%= f.radio_button :delivery_method, false %> <%= f.label :delivery_method, t, :style => 'padding-right: 10px' %> 
        <%if (i + 1) % 3 == 0 %><br> <%end%>        
        <% end %>
        <%= f.label :other_delivery_method, "Other:", :style => 'padding-right: 10px' %><%= f.text_field :other_delivery_method, :class => 'other_field' %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Let me know if you need any other code to help.  I've been stuck on this for a while.

Update method:

```
  def update_registration
    organization = Organization.find(params[:organization_id])
    @application = organization.auction_application
    p params[:auction_application]
    p "start"
    if @application.update_attributes(params[:auction_application])
      redirect_to auctions_path
    else
      Rails.logger.info(@application.errors.messages.inspect)
    end
    p "end"

  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `value` attribute to `false` while you should have set `checked` attribute:

```
<%= f.radio_button :delivery_method, '', checked: false %>
```

P.S. Now value is set to `''`, so you should set to whatever value you want.

Comment: Well, the form doesn't blow up with that change, however it won't successfully update the attributes now, with that change.

Comment: @m.sherman: show your controller method. By the way, have you replaced `''` with actual `value`?

Comment: What do you mean by "actual value"?   I replace it with "t".

Comment: @m.sherman: so now you are updating your `delivery_method` field with `t`.

Comment: gotcha, I edited my original post to include the controller method.